# How to get POS tags for merged phrases from Spacy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

I am currently working on an NLP problem where POS tagging is one of the essential steps. I was using Stanford CoreNLP for this task until I came across spaCy. I am new to spaCy and have been playing around with its online demo available at [explosion-Demo](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy)

For the given sentence:

> "My only disappointment with the 13" model is that they're the only
> ones in the MacBook Pro line up without an i5 or i7 processor and dual
> graphics cards, however, the trade-off is that you achieve a longer
> battery life (of about two more hours)."

The demo provided the following output:

> My only disappointment - NOUN with - ADP **the 13" model - NOUN** is - AUX
> that - SCONJ they - PRON 're - AUX the only ones - NOUN in - ADP the
> **MacBook Pro line - NOUN** up - ADP without - ADP **an i5 or i7 processor -
> NOUN** and - CCONJ **dual graphics cards, - NOUN**, however - ADV the
> trade-off - NOUN is - AUX that - SCONJ you - PRON achieve - VERB a
> **longer battery life ( - NOUN** of - ADP about two more hours). - NOUN

This output is perfect for my use case since it is tagging the word phrases (bold results) correctly. The way we can do this in the demo is by checking "merging punctuation" and "merging phrases."

**I was wondering if it is possible to get the same output via code?** I have done some research on this but haven't found anything useful so far. The thing which I came across multiple times is that you can merge chunks based on their tags.

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated!